# BS4 + html, b Tag issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This question is about web scraping with bs4

this is the code I have written:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

page = requests.get('https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Portable-Small-USB-Travel-LED-Makeup_60830030133.html?spm=a2700.details.maylikever.2.1fb53cc2uSVPvx')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#extract product score **(This is what I want to extract)**
stars = soup.select_one('a[class="score-lite"]', namespaces=None, flags=0)
#score = json.loads(stars)
print('Stars', stars)
```

My outcome:

```
<a class="score-lite" data-spm-click="gostr=/details.index.reviewLevel;locaid=dreviewLevel" href="https://onuliss.en.alibaba.com/company_profile/feedback.html" target="_blank"><b>4.8 </b><img src="//img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1MJPmiQL0gK0jSZFtXXXQCXXa-8-9.svg"/></a>
```

**The outcome I want is just the 4.8 number between the 'b' tags**
What do I have to do with the `= soup.select_one()` function?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a more specific selector, the `string` property of the match and `strip()` to get rid of eventual extra spaces.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

page = requests.get('https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Portable-Small-USB-Travel-LED-Makeup_60830030133.html?spm=a2700.details.maylikever.2.1fb53cc2uSVPvx')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#extract product score **(This is what I want to extract)**
stars = soup.select_one('a[class="score-lite"] > b', namespaces=None, flags=0).get_text(strip=True)
#score = json.loads(stars)
print('Stars', stars)
```

> Stars 4.8

Comment: I think it’s better to use `.content` than `.text` when parsing HTML/XML. Also, you probably want `.get_text()`, not `.string`.

Comment: Thanks @AMC, I switched to `get_text`, which conveniently also provides stripping. Not sure why I would want `content` instead of `text` though. Does BS4 work better with byte streams than with unicode strings?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak you don't need to use `.content` as 95% of websites already dealing with `UTF-8`, and `.content` usually cause `control characters` which is `\r\n\t` and also causing `whitespaces`. if we are talking about `HTML/XML` so according to the documentation. the best is to use `lxml` or `html5lib`. and you should know when to use `.get_text()` and `.text` or `.string` because there's a big difference .

Comment: Thank you very much! Checking your code I found that my mistake was not using `get_text(strip=True)`, also using: `stars = soup.select_one('a[class="score-lite"] ').get_text(strip=True)`  I can get the 4.8 result

Answer (score 0):

how about SimplifiedDoc

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
page = requests.get('https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Portable-Small-USB-Travel-LED-Makeup_60830030133.html?spm=a2700.details.maylikever.2.1fb53cc2uSVPvx')
# Create a SimplifiedDoc object
doc = SimplifiedDoc(page.text)
# get element use tag and class
stars = doc.getElement('a','class',"score-lite")
print('Stars', stars.text, stars.b.text) # Stars 4.8 4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(
    'https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Portable-Small-USB-Travel-LED-Makeup_60830030133.html?spm=a2700.details.maylikever.2.1fb53cc2uSVPvx')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

if r.status_code == 200:
    item = soup.find('a', {'class': 'score-lite'}).find('b')
    print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

output:

```
4.8
```